# What does the data in the MongoDB Map Reduce operation output mean? Is it possible to hide it?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, robo3t

So I have used the Map-Reduce paradigm for manipulating a MongoDB collection and have received the following output:

```
/* 1 */
{
"results" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : "B00000IKQD",
        "value" : 4.0
    }
],
"timeMillis" : 14.0,
"counts" : {
    "input" : 3,
    "emit" : 3,
    "reduce" : 1,
    "output" : 1
},
"ok" : 1.0,
"_o" : {
    "results" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "B00000IKQD",
            "value" : 4.0
        }
    ],
    "timeMillis" : 14,
    "counts" : {
        "input" : 3,
        "emit" : 3,
        "reduce" : 1,
        "output" : 1
    },
    "ok" : 1.0
},
"_keys" : [ 
    "results", 
    "timeMillis", 
    "counts", 
    "ok"
],
"_db" : {
    "_mongo" : {
        "slaveOk" : true,
        "host" : "localhost:27017",
        "defaultDB" : "test",
        "_readMode" : "commands"
    },
    "_name" : "vg"
    }
}
```

So I get that in the first array "results", it shows the output I have requested, but after that there is a lot of processed code.

Also, is there a way to hide all of that in the output?

EDIT:

So based on @AlexBlex answer, I just added '.results' as the end of the operation like so (and it works nicely):

```
db.P14165162_reviews.mapReduce(x, reduce,{
    out:{inline:1},
     query:{mts_asin:"B00000IKQD"},

}).results;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is documented at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#output

To "to hide all of that" you can return only results:

```
db.collection.mapReduce(......).results
```

Comment: As easy as that!